Installing Windows 11
Install windows 11 created on flash drive with windows creation tool.
installing from flash drive windows does not notice the c drive to install on.
I cannot figure out what the problem is.

What kind of disk physically? SATA or NVMe?

Verify that CSM is disabled and your drive has zero allocated partitions on it.  Windows 11 doesn’t support Legacy Mode or MBR. [Edit] your question and provide some additional information about your hardware

Some things to check:
Does the drive show up in BIOS?  If so, boot to the Win 11 flash drive and press SHIFT + F10 to launch a console.  Type diskpart then type list disk and see if the drive is listed.  If it's listed, type select disk <disk number> (e.g. select disk 0) and then type clean to delete all of the partitions.  Then refresh the list of drives in Windows Setup or reboot.  I haven't needed to manually install storage drivers in order to install Windows in a long time, but it's still a possibility.
